# I want to stop producing cells at 12 elements and save the remainder for another page

Tags: reactjs

The problem I have is that I am generating each cell component within the return. I'm really not sure how i can get around this.

```
import React from 'react';
import PokeCell from './PokeCell';
import './styles/PokeList.css';

const PokeList = (props) => {



    return (
        <section className="poke-list">
            {props.pokemon.map((pokemon, index) => (
                <PokeCell 
                    key={pokemon.id + index}
                    id={pokemon.id}
                    name={pokemon.name}
                    image={pokemon.image}
                />
            ))}
        </section>
    )
}

export default PokeList;
```

Comment: Are you wanting to implement pagination for your component? or just render the first few elements? you could always limit via the index `if (index > 11) return` but i'd probably just chunk the array so you only iterate what you need to

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you're looking for is pagination. One of the possible implementations could be to pass additional `page` and `itemsPerPage` props into your component. Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import PokeCell from './PokeCell';
import './styles/PokeList.css';

const PokeList = (props) => {
    const startIndex = props.page * props.itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = startIndex + props.itemsPerPage;

    return (
        <section className="poke-list">
            {props.pokemon.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((pokemon, index) => (
                <PokeCell 
                    key={pokemon.id + index}
                    id={pokemon.id}
                    name={pokemon.name}
                    image={pokemon.image}
                />
            ))}
        </section>
    )
}

export default PokeList;
```

The illustration of the principle:

```js
// NOTE: pages start from 0
const getPaginatedItems = (items, page, itemsPerPage) => {
  const startIndex = page * itemsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
  
  return items.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
};

const allItems = [
  'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4',
  'item 5', 'item 6', 'item 7'
];

console.log(getPaginatedItems(allItems, 2, 2));
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a clean way to do this is to pull the array generation code outside the return function. First, we take the first 12 item in the array using `slice(0,12)`. Then we use use `map` function to generate list of `<PokeCell>` and store at `pokemonCells`.

```
const PokeList = (props) => {
    const pokemonCells = props.pokemon.slice(0, 12).map((pokemon, index) => (
                <PokeCell 
                    key={pokemon.id + index}
                    id={pokemon.id}
                    name={pokemon.name}
                    image={pokemon.image}
                />
            ));


    return (
        <section className="poke-list">
            {pokemonCells} {/* render the JSX you stored in pokemonCells */}
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: this has no change in functionality to what the OP is describing.

Comment: This is also a something that could work for me. Thank you :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell  I think I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Well you updated after my comment to include the `slice` so the functionality has changed from the OP's code. What I was describing is doing the map outside of the return or not isn't going to chunk the rendered items until you do something like a `splice`. Now that you've edited its a more complete example. I'd probably change your slice indicies to be variable instead of fixed at 0 and 12 respectively.